# Enable Nginx warn/fail when missing variable used

Tags: nginx

I recently encountered an error on my site because I moved some config blocks to a sub-template and included it, and some needed variables didn't get scoped inside the included file. I'm using the latest OpenResty and some variables were set using Nginx's `set` and OpenResty's `set_md5`.

Nginx didn't complain at all, and I expected it to outright fail if there had been a problem. Is there any way to switch that sort of behavior on?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#uninitialized_variable_warn

Comment: Looks like that's on by default and I missed the warning. Any way to make it more obnoxious?